# What is the difference between Constructor and ngOnInit in Angular 5

Tags: angular, constructor, ngoninit

I have a parent class and child class in Angular. When trying to create a constructor inside child class it throws some error:

> Constructors for derived classes must contain a 'super' call.

It will be working if the code is added in `ngOnInit` instead of `constructor`. So what is the difference between these two? Both will be invoked up on instantiating the class.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Angular](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit),

**OnInit** is a callback method that is invoked immediately after the default change detector has checked the directive's data-bound properties for the first time, and before any of the view or content children have been checked. It is invoked only once when the directive is instantiated.

**Constructor** is similar to that of any class (with object oriented principles). And it's called when that class instance is created.

Also check [this](https://medium.com/@coderonfleek/constructor-vs-ngoninit-angular-2-components-b1a33db0be65).